# mahout recommendation custom item similarity

Tags: apache, mahout, recommendation-engine

I want to recommend jobs to user based on their skills using mahout.So is there any way i can define job similarity logic.
I found ItemSimilarity interface but not able to use it after custom implementation.

Comment: Is my question not clear?

i think it is a very common thing where i want to define my custom item similarity logic.

Answer (score 0):

In mahout, item similarity is based on the **User-Item interactions i.e. Preferences**. But if you want to have a custom item similarity as above, that comes under content based filtering. Every job will have set of features or dimensions(may be skills). Now you need to write a logic for calculating a similariy between two jobs based on their features. You can achieve this by using distnace measure techniques. Treat each job as a point in an m-dimentional space(say m skills) & calculate the distnace. Then you can calculate similariy as follows.
**similarity = (1 + 1/d).**

This gives similarity between 0 & 1(0 being least similar & 1 being most similar).

For distnace calculation you can use any of the distance measure techniques like Euclidean, Cosine or Tanimoto Coeffienct etc.